# Node.js: The npm bin -g command

Tags: node.js, npm

Can someone please explain to me the difference between the `npm bin -g` command and the `npm bin` command?

Practically, when I type `npm bin` I get `c:\wamp\www\node\node_modules\.bin`.

When I type `npm bin -g` (which is supposed to mean "global"), I get `c:\users\shmuli\appdata\roaming\npm`.

I'm assuming that "global" means that I can startup my program in cmd without having to be in the particular directory that it's installed... Do global installations have a different installation directory than typical installations?

Is that what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A global install means that a module is installed into a global folder which can be accessible from a script running from any directory.

Aside from having a different directory, a global install will install `man` pages for the module, as well as add a PATH variable for the module. That is why when modules have command-line interfaces, you're generally instructed to use `-g` when installing it.

For example, if you're running a script from `/path`, and you have a module named `foo` installed locally to that folder, you can only use `require('foo')` when inside `/path`. But if you installed `foo` globally, you can use `require('foo')` from a Node script anywhere on your file system because the global module folder is always checked.

Do note that if you install a module both locally and globally, and they're different modules, the module system will iterate up the file tree until it reaches the root of the drive. This means a locally installed module will be used over a globally installed module, because the locally installed module will be resolved to first.

---

As for the actual `npm bin` command itself, it prints the path that the package manager will install modules. If you pass the `-g` flag, then it prints the path that global modules are installed to.

Comment: Thanks again hex! You've been really helpful today! :)